Logic App Standard does not generate a Trigger-URL in Development Slot
I am facing the issue that my workflows with HTTP-Triggers ('When an HTTP request is received') in the development slot of my standard logic app don't have trigger url's generated after saving. In order to test the changes made in the development slot, I need the trigger URL's to call the development-workflow from my other app. This way I can see if the changes I made in the workflow work or not. In the production slot every 'When an HTTP request is received'-Trigger has a Trigger-URL which I obviously can call.
Does anyone know how the Trigger-URL's in a development slot work? Could it be that the URL's are never generated? If the URL's are generated, how do I get them in order to work with the development slot workflows?
This is the workflow in the production slot:
Workflow from Production-Slot
And here is the workflow from the development slot:
Workflow from Development-Slot
When I click 'save' it saves the workflow successfully but does not generate the Trigger-URL for the HTTP-Trigger in the development slot. Normally the URL should be generated automatically like it says in the second screenshot.

If I read this correctly, deployment slots are not supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/call-azure-functions-from-workflows?tabs=consumption#limitations or do you have a different szenario?
Could you maybe export the ARM Template and share it?

@JulianHüppauff I am deploying directly via VS Code, so there is no ARM Template I can share with you, respectively I don't know where where I can see the template used to deploy it. On the other hand it should be a very basic one.

@JulianHüppauff the Link you provided is about a different topic. There it says that calls from Azure Function API's with Managed Identities are not supported. In my case I use an HTTP-Trigger which triggers a logic app workflow. This link is not generated and I can't find a solution for this anywhere.

I have the same issue: HTTP URL is empty. I created the Logic App directly from VS Code (WS1 plan). How do I get the URL?


Could it be that the URL's are never generated? If the URL's are generated, how do I get them in order to work with the development slot workflows?

Its a known issue and limitation when you have deployed the workflows to a nonproduction slot.
These are the limitations when you are using nonproduction/development slot-

Nonproduction slots are created in read-only mode.

The nonproduction slots dispatcher is turned off, which means that workflows can only run when they're in the production slot.

Traffic distribution is disabled for deployment slots in Standard logic apps.

Deployment slots for Standard logic apps don't support the following scenarios:

Blue-green deployment
Product verification testing before slot swapping
A/B testing



As workflows can only run when they are in production slot. So, I believe this could be the reason that you are unable to see the endpoint and also you can't save it because its read only post deployment.
Also nonproduction slot is currently in preview mode. So, it is recommended to use the production slot if you would like to run the workflow.
